# Phalanger and php library for .net

Tags: c#, php, .net, phalanger

I have three php classes Im trying to use in my .net application.  I used Phalanger to take those three classes and make a .dll file using this command:

```
phpc /target:dll Client.php Crypt.php Exception.php
```

Which of course outputted Client.dll as well as a Client.pdb files.

From there I went to VS2012 and created a new asp.net application and added the Client.dll as a reference.  However I do not see the public methods from any of the classes and the object browser window shows:

> Client>Client>Base Types>Object (so that I only have the methods of
>   type Object)

I have tried [this](http://tomasp.net/blog/ducktyping-in-phalaner.aspx) method/tutorial to get it to work which involves casting a custom interface onto your object however I get the error:

> the type or namespace name ScriptContext could not be found

Which of course means that it doesnt know what or where ScriptContext.  However this tutorial is from 2007 so I dont know if its just to far out of date or where I should get that class from?

The [other tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17311/Phalanger-PHP-for-NET-Introduction-for-NET-develop#5_1) I found is just as old.  It says:

> If you want to use existing PHP source (developed for standard
>   interpreter) without modifications you have to use legacy mode, but
>   when you want to develop new PHP project you can consider using pure
>   mode

But I cannot find the step for legacy mode within the document and would prefer that over trying the "pure" mode (so that I dont have to change/edit my existing php code).  I did try (pure mode) however it wouldn't compile (phalanger compile) with the command above (adding the DynamicObject.php class to the command).

How can I get to my public methods within the php class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phpc /target:dll Client.php Crypt.php Exception.php
```

creates DLL in legacy (standard) mode. This DLL contains 'weird' namespaces, needed for compatibility with PHP semantics. (these namespaces separate code from different script files). [.NET interoperability overview of Phalanger 3.0](http://www.php-compiler.net/blog/2012/net-interoperability-overview-of-phalanger-3-0) blog post describes how to use scripts compiled in standard mode.

Command line option `/pure+` tells compiler to create so-called pure mode assembly. In this mode, compiler concatenates all the source files and compiles them as one (as C# does), without any weird namespaces. If you specify `[\Export]` attribute above the PHP class declaration, resulting DLL will look as it would be compiled from C# code, and you will be able to reference it and use its classes normally.

Comment: If you have a phalanger project in visual studio, go to properties, and change Mode to Pure.

Comment: Great link thanks!  Part of my problem however is that I cannot find the class ScriptContext.  The doc mentions that VS express edition isn't support, so is that why I do not see that class?

Comment: PHP.Core.ScriptContext is in PhpNetCore.dll ... VS Express has no  support for 3rd party plugins - this means you cannot install Phalanger Tools plugin that utilize Phalanger/PHP projects and editor features, but it won't affect C# editor experience

Comment: Thank you, I didnt realize that I had to browse to it at the "C:\Program Files\Phalanger 3.0\Bin" folder for that.

Comment: If you get a chance please check out my followup question (about the fact that phalanger isnt seeing my php classes)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901567/phalanger-cant-find-my-php-classes