# Phalanger cant find my php classes

Tags: c#, php, phalanger

After [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845562/phalanger-and-php-library-for-net) I found a good (up to date) example to follow [here](http://www.php-compiler.net/blog/2012/net-interoperability-overview-of-phalanger-3-0).  I successfully got PHP.Core libraries working in VS but still having problems finding my php classes.

The tutorial is simple enough however

```
dynamic phpObj = globals.@class.PhpClass();
```

never finds my php class.  I have tried with the example file default.php (classname: PhpClass) and with my own php classes which are similar but have a different name.

What am I missing here?  I have tried the option

> Project Properties>Package/Publish Web>Items to deploy>all files in
>   project

but that didnt help.  Currently I have my php classes just under the project as seen below
[image]

The error I get just says it cant find the class:
[image]

Using ILSpy here is the main snippet of code for CurrentContext

```
result = (((ScriptContext)CallContext.GetData("PhpNet:ScriptContext")) ?? ScriptContext.CreateDefaultScriptContext());
```

This is the line of code that is used to find the php classes (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include your php files into the PHP context first ... 
In Web App, to 'simulate' php lifecycle properly, do following:

```
using (var request_context = RequestContext.Initialize(ApplicationContext.Default, HttpContext.Current))
{
    var context = request_context.ScriptContext;
    context.Include("default.php", false);
// now the declarations declared by default.php are available in context.
// do anything with PHP objects here
}
```